# Sum of DataLength values does not match table size

Tags: sql-server, datalength

I am trying to find which user records in a table are taking up the most space. To this end, I am using the `DATALENGTH` function in SqlServer.

```
SELECT 
    UserName, 
    SUM(
        ISNULL(DATALENGTH(columnA), 1) +
        ISNULL(DATALENGTH(columnB), 1) +
        ....
        ISNULL(DATALENGTH(columnZ), 1) +
        )/1000000 AS SizeInMegaBytes
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UserName
ORDER BY SizeInMegaBytes DESC
```

Results:

```
+----------+-----------------+
| UserName | SizeInMegaBytes |
+----------+-----------------+
|   User1  |       1700      |
+----------+-----------------+
|   User2  |       1504      |
+----------+-----------------+
|   ....   |       ....      |
+----------+-----------------+
|  User75  |        20       |
+----------+-----------------+
```

**Total Size = 16,523 MB**

The only problem is that the results don't match up with the size of the table. I use the built-in stored procedure to get the size of the table

```
sp_spaceused [MyTable]
```

Results:

```
+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| name    | rows  | reserved    | data        | index_size | unused      |
+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| MyTable | 61477 | 59425416 KB | 42482152 KB | 62584 KB   | 16880680 KB |
+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

The stored procedure shows the total data size as 42 GB yet the query of all the columns shows 16 GB. What could be taking up the extra space if I have accounted for the size of all the columns?

EDIT - I don't think my issue is the same as the duplicate mentioned because here I am taking the `SUM` of all the grouped records while the previous question did not. There seems to be such a large disparity between the SUM of the DataLength function and the results of `sp_spaceused` (29 GB) I don't think it could be accounted for by indexes or header information alone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between sp\_spaceused and DataLength SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768320/difference-between-sp-spaceused-and-datalength-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

First; your math is suspect; 1MB = (1KB * 1KB) = 1024B * 1024B

Second; there could be metadata associated with table and records.  Inspecting the table definition can give insight here.

Comment: I see what you are saying about the math, however, if I change the query to `/ 1048576` is still doesn't account for the difference between 16 GB and 42 GB. Where is the extra 26 GB coming from?

Comment: If I am remembering correctly, space used is a combination of multiple fields. You may want to check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql)

Comment: @Jacob - I think you are right. That is why I included all columns in the SELECT statement

Comment: 26G is a lot of missing data.   I'm not sure indexes would account for it.

This thread has a script one user wrote as well to do what you're trying to do, it might be worth checking out.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4ce0aaac-11a1-407b-b2ee-fdd588b52e37/calculating-table-size?forum=sqltools